# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[188] = [50,0] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [50,50]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am getting an error below:

*InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[188] = [50,0] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [50,50]

[[Node: SparseToDense = SparseToDense[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](concat, SparseToDense/output_shape, ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample:5, SparseToDense/default_value)]]*

Below is my code

```
def count_matrix_input(filenames, submatrix_rows, submatrix_cols):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
  reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={
          'global_row': tf.FixedLenFeature([submatrix_rows], dtype=tf.int64),
          'global_col': tf.FixedLenFeature([submatrix_cols], dtype=tf.int64),
          'sparse_local_row': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
          'sparse_local_col': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
          'sparse_value': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32)
      })

  global_row = features['global_row']
  global_col = features['global_col']

  sparse_local_row = features['sparse_local_row'].values
  sparse_local_col = features['sparse_local_col'].values
  sparse_count = features['sparse_value'].values

  sparse_indices = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[tf.expand_dims(sparse_local_row, 1),
                                         tf.expand_dims(sparse_local_col, 1)])
  count = tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices, [submatrix_rows, submatrix_cols], sparse_count)
  queued_global_row, queued_global_col, queued_count = tf.train.batch(
  [global_row, global_col, count], batch_size=1, num_threads=FLAGS.num_readers, capacity=32)

  queued_global_row = tf.reshape(queued_global_row, [submatrix_rows])
  queued_global_col = tf.reshape(queued_global_col, [submatrix_cols])
  queued_count = tf.reshape(queued_count, [submatrix_rows, submatrix_cols])

  return queued_global_row, queued_global_col, queued_count
```

Where I have assigned submatrix_row and submatrix_col to be 50.

And my other question is, why is it out of bounts if it is acutally inside [50,50]??